# Why isn't a HD Video in 720p played without stops and glitches?

Tags: video, drivers, codecs, hd-video

When I try to watch a video with a high HD Resolution 1280 x 720 H264 in Ubuntu it isn't played smoothly. Stops and glitches occur. I don't think this is a problem with the CPU or graphics card, because under Windows there are no problems like this. Could it be a driver problem?

Update: For me VLC Player works best. No stops and no glitches. Smplayer also looks good but the performance leaks similarly to the standard Ubuntu video player in my case.

Comment: What player are you using? I personally have different experience on different players.

Comment: Are you using Flash? Or are you referring to a video playing in something like Totem?

Comment: Try VLC player. It plays many "difficult" formats smoothly.

Comment: the problems occur with the standart player in ubuntu. i currently checked vlc player and i'm impressed. it works so much better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't compare Windows and Linux, because video driver performance and features are different. For instance, if you are using nVidia you need a card that supports [vdpau](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VDPAU) for best performance, which is equivalent to [PureVideo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nvidia_PureVideo) in Windows. PureVideo supports many more cards. However, depending on your CPU, you can play HD videos smoothly without vdpau support. So it depends on your video driver, CPU and also player settings.

It would help if you could provide more info about your video card and CPU.

Anyway, try [smplayer](http://packages.ubuntu.com/smplayer) [image: Install smplayer]

It's the best player IMO and plays even videos with resolutions higher than 1080p on my Core2 Duo with nVidia 7300 GT (not vdpau).

Make sure you tweak smplayer. In the **Preferences**, click the **Performance** section and select the option **Skip only on HD videos** in the **Loop filter** settings. In the **General** section, click the **Video** tab and make sure the **Output** driver is set to **xv**.

Comment: The Notebook is not the latest but performance should suffice for play smoothly. Dual Core CPU 1,8 and a Ati Card with i know i learned is not the best choice for ubuntu :) I'll give smplayer a try also.

Comment: Smplayer also plays with glitches and not smoothly in spite i tweaked it with your settingsadvices. at the moment it looks as if only vlc is the only player at the moment to run smoothly.

Comment: Try to disable Desktop effects (Compiz). Anyway, if VLC works stick with it.

Comment: until xvba becomes a reality, ati is not the best choice for hd videos on linux.

Comment: before i switched completly to linux, i wasn't aware that ati isn't the best choice for a linux system. however in the meantime i think i have also learned that the ati cards also aren't the best choice at all (for windows) imho.